# Split array elements into multiple strings

Tags: bash

I have this array:

```
info=('John;10;03-03-2019;john@123' 'Mike;20;20;03-03-2019;mike@123')
```

I need to separate this as follows:

- [0] John  10 years at 03-03-2019
- [1] Mike  20 years at 03-03-2019

I only have this:

```
IFS=';' read -r -a ADDR <<< "$info"

for i in "${ADDR[@]}; 
do
    echo -n "Name:$i"
done
```

Comment: now the array is ok sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
newinfo=()
for item in "${info[@]}"; do 
    IFS=";" read -ra fields <<<"$item" 
    newinfo+=("${fields[0]} ${fields[1]} years at ${fields[2]}")
done
declare -p newinfo
```

```
declare -a newinfo=([0]="John 10 years at 03-03-2019" [1]="Mike 20 years at 20")
```

---

Alternately:

```sh
newinfo=()
for item in "${info[@]}"; do 
    IFS=";" read -ra fields <<<"$item" 
    printf -v newinfo[i++] "%s %s years at %s" "${fields[@]:0:3}"
done
```

The `i` variable will be treated as zero when it is used for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can split a specific array entry info[ix] into fields using the following read statement

```
IFS=';' read name years date email <<< "${info[$ix]}"

echo "Name=$name, email=$email, ..."
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the question. Can you clarify 'I can do the for' ?